# How to check if a field has been indexed

Tags: solr, lucene

I recently updated my SOLR config and run again the import query.
Data is present but still I can't filter by a new field I just added.

How can I check the new field has beed indexed correctly?

Possibly doing this from the SOLR console.

Comment: Solr Admin -> Select core / collection -> Schema - it'll show you the settings for each field .

Answer (score 0):

If you are able to search on the field then you can be sure that the field is indexed.

The other option is to go to the solr analysis page and check if the field is indexed or not.

The last option could be go to the solr analysis page and check the schema file if it updated for a particular core or the collection which you are referring.

[image: solr schema file]